# Display data retrieved using PHP function in front end without using global variables

Tags: php, html, class, object, global-variables

I have a database where there is a table named member. Member has different columns like mem_id mem_image, mem_thumbnail, mem_phone, mem_email, city_name etc. There are more than 200 entries in this table amounting to 200 different mem_ids. 
I have a php function inside a class which I use to execute the mysql query.

```
class myClass{

    public function __construct(){}

    public function memDetails($conn,$cityName)
    {

        global $memId;
        global $memImage;
        global $memThumb;
        global $memPhone;
        global $memEmail;


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE mem_id=$memId";

        $mem_details = $this->query($conn,$sql);

        foreach ($mem_details as $setValue) {
            $memId= $setValue->mem_id;
            $memImage= $setValue->mem_image;
            $memThumb= $setValue->mem_thumbnail;
            $memPhone= $setValue->mem_phone;
            $memEmail= $setValue->mem_email;

    }
}
```

Now in the Php front end page where I want to display the data, I first create an object of the class myClass and then call the function memDetails

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        // database connection code here
        $obj = new myClass();
        $obj->memDetails($conn, $memId);
        <p>Image URL= <?PHP echo $memImage ?></p>
        <p>Thumb URL= <?PHP echo $memThumb ?></p>
        <p>Phone= <?PHP echo $memPhone ?></p>
        <p>Email= <?PHP echo $memEmail ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason I am doing this is because I need to use this function in different pages to retrieve the data for member. And that is exactly why I have declared the variables as global so that I can use them in all pages after I call that function. But as I have heard it is not wise to use global as it gets difficult to keep track of all global variables and also one change in its name will need me to change it across all pages.

So which is the way by which I can do this better and efficient and need less of php code in the front end php page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few loose ends in your question, but to keep things simple, I'd advise you to return something from memDetails method. For example

```
class myClass{

    public function __construct(){}

    public function memDetails($conn,$memId)
    {

        $result=[];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE mem_id=$memId";

        $mem_details = $this->query($conn,$sql);

        foreach ($mem_details as $setValue) {
            $result['memId'] = $setValue->mem_id;
            $result['memImage'] = $setValue->mem_image;
            $result['memThumb'] = $setValue->mem_thumbnail;
            $result['memPhone'] = $setValue->mem_phone;
            $result['memEmail'] = $setValue->mem_email;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

would return an associative array, so you could later do

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        // database connection code here
        $obj = new myClass();
        $result = $obj->memDetails($conn, $memId);
        <p>Image URL= <?PHP echo $result['memImage'] ?></p>
        <p>Thumb URL= <?PHP echo $result['memThumb'] ?></p>
        <p>Phone= <?PHP echo $result['memPhone'] ?></p>
        <p>Email= <?PHP echo $result['memEmail'] ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

That way, myClass doesn't need to know anything about the vars in the outer or global scope whatsoever.

There are other ways to go about this. Each $setValue attribute could, instead, be assigned to a member variable, but then you would need to keep different instances of myClass to avoid mixing the results. In this solution you only instance myClass once and then you can reuse `memDetails` over and over again with different $memId.

Comment: Thanks @amenadiel . Will try this out now.